# Allow VPN to external site through ISA 2006 firewall

Tags: vpn, pptp, isa-server

I'v followed the instrutions from here, but still it doesn't connect. (while the VPN setup does work when I try via my home network)

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;838245

When I try connect I get this in the logs (Mac)

```
pppd: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
```

Also for debugging purposes, is there non-destructive way to temporarily disable the ISA firewall?

**Edit:**

Wow I thought I had added that.
What type of VPN is it?

- PPTP

#### What OS'es are involved?

#### What's the VPN Server Software?

- VPN is hosted on Windows Small Business Server 2011
- Connecting from Windows Small Business Server 2003 (all updates applied)
- Also tried connecting from Mac OS X 10.7.4
- I can connect fine when I use my home network.

#### Client Software?

- System default. (e.g. Mac **System Preferences** > **Network** > **+** > **VPN**, **PPTP**)

#### Anything in the ISA Logs?

- Will have to check. I find digging through ISA 2006 logs rather tricky.

Comment: Please add some more information. What type of VPN is it? What OS'es are involved? What's the VPN Server Software? Client Software? Anything in the ISA Logs?

Comment: Added, will add ISA logs soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would try to backup the ISA 2006 configuration , and make planning before changing something in ISA 2006 firewall , and commit the change at some hour where ISA has a low impact (be aware that in conflicting settings , ISA might lock all the connections so you might need to be physically near the server )

I would go with :

1. In Built traffic simulator in ISA 2006 to try and test different ranges and rules
2. Check if you don't have some limitations on the internal network for port ranges and check if ISA is configured in DMZ (for external network ) . Are there any limitation in place for the connection between DMZ and internal network ? You could test this from a separate wireless network and see the outcome .